# Running PowerShell as another user, and launching a script

Tags: powershell, runas

I won't get into all the details of why I need this, but users must be able to launch PowerShell as a service account and when PowerShell loads it needs to run a script. I already can launch PowerShell with the stored credentials (stored as a secure string), but for the life of me I cannot get the script (located in $args) to run. I have tried a variety of things, and below is where I am currently. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$user = "domain\service.account" 
$pwd1 = "big long huge string of characters"
$pwd = ($pwd1 | ConvertTo-SecureString)
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $user, $pwd
$args = "\\domain.local\location\location\location\Script\script.ps1"
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $Credential -ArgumentList ("-file $args")
```

Comment: When I try to run as different user, nothing happens. Is there some kind of policy in my server against that?

Answer (score 111):

You can open a new powershell window under a specified user credential like this:

```
start powershell -credential ""
```

[image]

Comment: Somehow, when I use this method, I can't type anything into newly opened powershell window. Using trick from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44797801/1108916 works, though. Sigh.

Comment: Oh weird, if you close the parent powershell window, the new child one can receive keyboard input

Comment: Because, It is the feature from windows by default.

Answer (score 62):

I found this worked for me.

```
$username = 'user'
$password = 'password'

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword
Start-Process Notepad.exe -Credential $credential
```

Updated: changed to using single quotes to avoid special character issues noted by Paddy.

Comment: I had to put my password in single quotes since it contained 'special' characters. You can check the password has been stored correctly by writing `$password` at the prompt, it will print what is stored in the variable

Comment: Thanks @Paddy, I've updated the code to reflect your comment.

Comment: probably best to default to using single quotes in practice.  helps avoid unintended issues cropping up--saving double quotes for when you intend to use them for a specific purpose.

Comment: I feel like this should be the go-to solution for all the 'Run As' issues people face due to execution restrictions. Personally, I have tried a lot of solutions on SO and found this to be the only working one.

Comment: **Security remark** This stores the password in plain text in the script, which is usually a bad idea.

Comment: @user202729 Very good point. Make sure you don't store your passwords in your scripts! Pull them in from environment variables or other data stores.

Answer (score 61):

Here's also nice way to achieve this via UI.

0) Right click on PowerShell icon when on task bar

1) Shift + right click on Windows PowerShell

2) "Run as different user"

[image: Pic]

Answer (score 9):

Try adding the `RunAs` option to your `Start-Process`

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $Credential -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList ("-file $args")
```

Comment: Thanks, I eventually saw the reason for the credentials prompt. The massive string used is too large, so I need to look at other options for storing and/or converting this password.

Comment: Adding `-Verb RunAs` yields me a `Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.` My other parameters are -Wait, -Credential $creds, -WorkingDirectory C:\ -ArgumentList "..." This is with powershell 5.

Answer (score 3):

In windows server 2012 or 2016 you can search for Windows PowerShell and then "Pin to Start". After this you will see "Run as different user" option on a right click on the start page tiles.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a credential popup that will get the username and password as strings like this:

[image]

```
#Get credentials
$credential = Get-Credential
$username = $credential.Username
$password = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

Then you can use in your script the variables $username and $password

Answer (score 3):

This command works for me:

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $Credential -ArgumentList "-file $FILE"
```

If the `$FILE` is on network, make sure the run-as user can access the file.

---

## Script

I just created a script to make it easier for automation:

```
 <#

.SYNOPSIS

Run command as another user.

.DESCRIPTION

Run batch or PowerShell command as another user.

.PARAMETER Command

The batch command you'd like to execute as another user.

.PARAMETER ScriptBlock

The PowerShell command you'd like to execute as another user.

.PARAMETER Username

Run the command as what user.

.PARAMETER Password

Password of the user.

.PARAMETER Credential

PowerShell credential of the user, it can be generated by `Get-Credential`.

.PARAMETER Wait

Wait command to complete or not.
Command output would not be displayed if it is not specified.

#>

Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "bat-user-password")]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "bat-credential")]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]
    $Command,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "ps-user-password")]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "ps-credential")]
    [ScriptBlock]
    $ScriptBlock,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "bat-user-password")]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "ps-user-password")]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]
    $Username,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "bat-user-password")]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "ps-user-password")]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]
    $Password,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "bat-credential")]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "ps-credential")]
    [PSCredential]
    $Credential,

    [Switch]
    $Wait
)

$IsCurrentAdminUser = $([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] 'Administrator')

# Find a dir that every user have full access to
$TempDir = "$env:SystemDrive\Users\Public\run_as"
if (-not (Test-Path -Path $TempDir)) {
    $null = New-Item -Path $TempDir -ItemType Directory
    attrib +h $TempDir
}

# Generate a uniq id for problem tracking
$ExecId = Get-Random -Maximum 99999999 -Minimum 10000000

# Temp files
$UserScriptPrefix = "$TempDir\$ExecId-UserScript"
$UserStdOut = "$TempDir\$ExecId-UserStdOut.log"
$UserErrOut = "$TempDir\$ExecId-UserErrOut.log"
$WaitFile = "$TempDir\$ExecId-Running"

$ExecScript = "$TempDir\$ExecId-Exec.ps1"
$CmdToExec = "Start-Process"

if ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName.StartsWith('bat')) {
    $UserScript = $UserScriptPrefix + '.bat'
    $Command |Out-File -FilePath $UserScript -Encoding ascii

    $CmdToExec += " cmd.exe -ArgumentList '/c $UserScript'"
} elseif ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName.StartsWith('ps')) {
    $UserScript = $UserScriptPrefix + '.ps1'
    $ScriptBlock |Out-File -FilePath $UserScript -Encoding ascii

    $CmdToExec += " PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-file $UserScript'"
}

if ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName.EndsWith('user-password')) {
    $SecPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -Force
    $Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($Username, $SecPassword)
}

$CmdToExec += " -WorkingDirectory $env:SystemDrive\"

if ($Wait) {
    # Redirect output only if -Wait flag is set
    $CmdToExec += " -RedirectStandardError $UserErrOut"
    $CmdToExec += " -RedirectStandardOutput $UserStdOut"

    if ($IsCurrentAdminUser) {
        # -Wait parameter of Start-Process only works with admin users
        # Using it with non-admin users will get an "Access is denied" error
        $CmdToExec += " -Wait"
    }
}

$script = @'
Param($Cred)
"" | Out-File -FilePath {0}

try {{
    {1} -Credential $Cred
}} catch {{
    Write-Host $_
}} finally {{
    Remove-Item -Path {0} -Force -Confirm:$false
}}
'@ -f $WaitFile, $CmdToExec

$Script |Out-File -FilePath $ExecScript -Encoding ascii

try {
    & $ExecScript -Cred $Credential
} catch {
    Write-Host $_
} finally {
    if ($Wait) {
        if (-not $IsCurrentAdminUser) {
            # Impelment the wait by file monitoring for non-admin users
            do {
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
            } while (Test-Path -Path $WaitFile)
    
            # Wait output are write to files completely
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        }

        # Read command output from files
        if (Test-Path -Path $UserStdOut) {
            Get-Content -Path $UserStdOut
        }

        if (Test-Path -Path $UserErrOut) {
            Get-Content -Path $UserErrOut
        }
    }

    Remove-Item -Path "$TempDir\$ExecId-*" -Force -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

Copy the content and save to a `*.ps1` file, like `run_as.ps1`.

## Document

Show build-in doucment:

```
PS C:\> Get-Help C:\run_as.ps1 -detailed

NAME
    C:\run_as.ps1

SYNOPSIS
    Run command as another user.


SYNTAX
    C:\run_as.ps1 -Command <String> -Credential <PSCredential> [-Wait] [<CommonParameters>]

    C:\run_as.ps1 -Command <String> -Username <String> -Password <String> [-Wait] [<CommonParameters>]

    C:\run_as.ps1 -ScriptBlock <ScriptBlock> -Credential <PSCredential> [-Wait] [<CommonParameters>]

    C:\run_as.ps1 -ScriptBlock <ScriptBlock> -Username <String> -Password <String> [-Wait] [<CommonParameters>]


DESCRIPTION
    Run batch or PowerShell command as another user.


PARAMETERS
......
```

## Examples

#### 01

Current user is administrator, run batch command as user01 with password

**Note**: Please DO NOT use plain password in production environment. You can use it for testing.
In a production environment, you can use `-Credential` option instead.

```
PS C:\> whoami
test-win-1\administrator
PS C:\> .\run_as.ps1 -Command 'whoami' -Username 'user01' -Password 'password1'
PS C:\> 
PS C:\> # Add -Wait to get command output
PS C:\> .\run_as.ps1 -Command 'whoami' -Username 'user01' -Password 'password1' -Wait

C:\>whoami
test-win-1\user01
PS C:\> 
PS C:\> # Add '@' to batch command to avoid the header lines
PS C:\> .\run_as.ps1 -Command '@whoami' -Username 'user01' -Password 'password1' -Wait
test-win-1\user01
PS C:\>
```

#### 02

Current user is administrator, run PowerShell command as user02 with password

**Note**: Please DO NOT use plain password in production environment. You can use it for testing.
In a production environment, you can use `-Credential` option instead.

```
PS C:\> $env:USERPROFILE
C:\Users\Administrator
PS C:\> .\run_as.ps1 -ScriptBlock {$env:USERPROFILE} -Username 'user02' -Password 'password2' -Wait
C:\Users\user02
PS C:\>
```

#### 03

Current user is administrator, run PowerShell command as user02 with its credential

```
PS C:\> $env:USERPROFILE
C:\Users\Administrator
PS C:\> $cred = Get-Credential user02    # input user02's password in the pop-up window
PS C:\> .\run_as.ps1 -ScriptBlock {$env:USERPROFILE} -Credential $cred -Wait
C:\Users\user02
PS C:\>
```

#### 04

Current user is user01, run PowerShell command as administrator

```
PS C:\> $(Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Administrator\).FullName                                                                                 
Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Users\Administrator' is denied.                                                                    
At line:1 char:3                                                                                                                          
+ $(Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Administrator\).FullName                                                                                       
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                 
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Users\Administrator\:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException             
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand                                
                                                                                                                                        
PS C:\> whoami                                                                                                                            
test-win-1\user01                                                                                                                         
PS C:\> # Standard user cannot access administrator user's home directory
PS C:\> 
PS C:\> .\run_as.ps1 -ScriptBlock {$(Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Administrator\).FullName} -Username Administrator -Password 'adminpasswd' -Wait  
C:\Users\Administrator\.vscode                                                                                                            
C:\Users\Administrator\3D Objects                                                                                                         
C:\Users\Administrator\Contacts                                                                                                           
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop                                                                                                            
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents                                                                                                          
C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads                                                                                                          
C:\Users\Administrator\Favorites                                                                                                          
C:\Users\Administrator\Links                                                                                                              
C:\Users\Administrator\Music                                                                                                              
C:\Users\Administrator\Pictures                                                                                                           
C:\Users\Administrator\Saved Games                                                                                                        
C:\Users\Administrator\Searches                                                                                                           
C:\Users\Administrator\Videos                                                                                                             
PS C:\>
```

Comment: This script is great, but you should add a note that if you do NOT supply the `-password` it will prompt you for it, which is WAY more secure than having it in your command history.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have added notes for that. You're right, but the bad thing is that you need to input password every time. If you use the `-Credential`, the PSCrednetial object only need to be created one time and can be used for many times.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. This is helpful in remote servers where you just a have remote command line tool available to use.

```
runas /user:Administrator "powershell Start-Transcript -Path C:\Users\m\testlog.txt;import-module 'C:\Users\m\script.ps1';Stop-Transcript"
```

This will also ensure that you can get the output of the command in `testlog.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

As far as I can tell, your script is correct because your credential is in the form of `<domain>\<user>`

But, I have two questions:

1. Does your service user have sufficient permissions to access the script you want to run in the location from which you want to run it?
2. Does your service user have sufficient permissions to exist in the directory from which you are running PowerShell?

If your answer to #1 is no, well, you know how to fix that.

If your answer to #2 is no, then specify `-WorkingDirectory <path>` where `<path>` is the location of the script (because you've already fixed/verified any permission issues), or a location to which the service user has access.