# How to prompt to run EXE as different user in powershell

Tags: powershell, uac, elevated-privileges, runas

How would I go about running an EXE as a different user?  How could I prompt for credentials or atleast ask for the password for a local admin to launch an exe through powershell.  I'm having a hard time getting the runas command to work.

This was the latest thing I tried:
runas -credential .\me c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe

This works in the powershell terminal:
runas /user:asdf c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe but doesn't ask for credentials in a standalone powershell script.

Comment: *"I'm having a hard time getting the runas command to work:* please show [as a edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33377545/edit) what you tried to make the runas command work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running PowerShell as another user, and launching a script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989750/running-powershell-as-another-user-and-launching-a-script)

Comment: Please give @Nick credit and mark it answered.

Comment: It works in PowerShell commandline shell, because powershell can run most executables from the commandline.  `Start-Process` and `Invoke-Command` are used to run commands (PS or external) as if they were run from the commandline.

Answer (score 5):

This is a simple operation.

```
Start-Process "c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe" -Credential $(Get-Credential)
```

Using Get-Credential will prompt the user for credentials, You can also store it in a variable.

```
$Creds = Get-Credential
Start-Process "c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe" -Credential $Creds
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
Start-Process notepad.exe -Verb RunAsUser
```

Answer (score 0):

change directory to .exe directory and run below command

```
runas /netonly /user:<domain\username> .\<app name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't judge me for my credential handling!

```
$Pwd=ConvertTo-SecureString -String "<password>" -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred=[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::new("<domain>\<username>",$Pwd)
Start-Process -FilePath "<path to .EXE>" -Credential $Cred -WorkingDirectory "~"
```

Why this worked:

1. Credentials in the form of `<user>@<domain>` don't work for some reason.  you have to use the old Windows NT format.
2. If you don't specify the `WorkingDirectory`, PowerShell will use the current directory.  So, if your target user doesn't have permissions there, you'll get the error, "`Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The directory name is invalid.`"