# Connect from admin to domain account using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to install dfs replication group using powershell commands but the problem is when I login as administrator I cannot create replication group as it through error that system is not in domain.
when I login via domain user and password , command runs perfectly. So my requirement is once I login as administrator I can switch to domain user via powershell and run below command:

```
New-DfsReplicationGroup -GroupName "RG01"
```

Thanks

Comment: If you can run the command as a domain user, why can't you simply run the command as a domain user?

Comment: As per my requirement I cannot use domain user directly ..It was just to check I asked permission from respective team.

Comment: This is hacky but you could `Invoke-Command` with the credentials of the domain user.

Comment: Basically its like doing ssh but in powershell.

Comment: I wouldn't say that. Plus while you can use it remotely, that's not a requirement.

Comment: Thanks Jacob !!! I tried invoke but not working ..I can also ping to domain..PS C:\Users\Administrator> Invoke-Command user@example.com
Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.At line:1 char:1 + Invoke-Command user@example.com + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeComm

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: or if I cannot login can I run commands using domain user ? like user@example:New-DfsReplicationGroup -GroupName "RG01"

Comment: You're not using the correct syntax, try using `Get-Help Invoke-Command` or looking at ms docs. You seem to be thinking of it like SSH, which it is not. You cannot "attach" to anything using this, and explore the filesystem, or anything akin to that. You need to pass it a script block, in the least. You will likely need to create a powershell session with a credential object, and pass that in as well.

Comment: You could try this too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989750/running-powershell-as-another-user-and-launching-a-script

Comment: It prompts for password but fails PS C:\Users\Administrator> Invoke-Command -ComputerName  WIN-1U.example.com  -Credential example.com\User -ScriptBlock {New-DfsReplicationGroup -GroupName "RG01"}
Could not create the replication group named "RG01". An operation error occurred.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (System.String[]:String[]) [New-DfsReplicationGroup], DfsrException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : New-DfsReplicationGroup.TerminatingOMException,Microsoft.DistributedFileSystemReplicatio   n.Commands.NewDfsReplicationGroupCommand
    + PSComputerName   : WIN-1U.example.com

Comment: Thanks Jacob !!! I look into the provided link...