# "Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: Access is denied." when specifying credentials?

Tags: powershell

Good morning :S.

I can enter into a PSSession and execute cmdlets just fine, however, as soon as I specify an account to use, it just throws back an access is denied error. I've even tested with the same account and password that established the PSSession. This works locally just fine.

I am trying to integrate this into an SCCM application, so there isn't a whole lot of wiggle room.

EDIT: I put an easier code that doesn't work either below:

```
$username = 'DOMAIN\Username'
$password = 'P@ssword'

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword
Start-Process Notepad.exe  -Credential $credential
```

```
#Execute variable 
$myCommand = "'C:\Program Files (x86)\PGP Corporation\PGP Desktop\pgpwde' --status --disk 0"

#Credential Variables
$username = 'DOMAIN\USERNAME'
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'P@ssword' -Force -AsPlainText
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential -ArgumentList $username, $Password

#Expression Variable
$expression = @"
    try
    {
        & $myCommand | Out-File `C:\test.txt -Force
    }
    catch
    {
        `$_.Exception.Message | Out-File `C:\ERROR.txt -Force
    }
"@

#Execute 
Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-c $expression" -Credential $credential
```

Comment: Are you getting the "Access Denied" on `C:\ERROR.txt` or on your PS Host?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon No, there is no output at all. It blocks from running the ```Start-Process...```

Comment: Try adding `-Verb RunAs` to `Start-Process`. Sounds like `$username` doesn't have permissions to run as locally. You could use this link to troubleshoot your issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/shell-experience/access-denied-runas-command-run-as-administrator. Also this post may point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989750/running-powershell-as-another-user-and-launching-a-script/34307483

Comment: I'll try that, but I am admin on the box

Comment: Yeah, your user might be a local admin but the user you're trying to impersonate might not be.

Comment: I added my credentials into the script to test, yet that didn't work.