# switch user "su -" equivalent in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

How can I switch users on the PS command prompt?

When I start PS, I get the following:

```
PS C:/Users/neo>
```

I want to switch users (similar to su - trinity in linux) so that I get something like this:

```
PS C:/Users/trinity>
```

The reason I want to switch users is because only trinity has write and execute permissions on some PS scripts on the Windows Server.

Comment: [runas - Running PowerShell as another user, and launching a script - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989750/running-powershell-as-another-user-and-launching-a-script) ?