# Powershell - cannot 'use another account' when running Azure delegated permission app

Tags: azure, powershell

I have been using Graph API in Powershell using application permission for a while now and I would like to explore how delegated permissions work.

I come across the website which is great.
https://morgantechspace.com/2021/10/how-to-register-and-configure-azure-ad-application-from-azure-ad-portal.html

I basically copy and run the code below after I created the app.
**When I ran the code, a MFA prompt popped up which is what I expected.
However, I was never able to choose another account to log on.
It always defaults to the account which I used to run Powershell.**
Is there anyway I could get around it?

[image]

```
$TenantId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
$AppClientId="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  
 $MsalParams = @{
    ClientId = $AppClientId
    TenantId = $TenantId
    Scopes   = "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read"
}
 
$MsalResponse = Get-MsalToken @MsalParams
$AccessToken  = $MsalResponse.AccessToken#Provide Application (client) Id of your app
```

Answer (score 0):

***We have tried the same by following the given [***article***](https://morgantechspace.com/2021/10/how-to-register-and-configure-azure-ad-application-from-azure-ad-portal.html) and can able to select our another account(*Admin*) and able to get the access token successfully.***

*Here are the workaround we have tried :-*

- *Created an app registration and provided the `redirect uri` and given the API permission with Granted Admin consents as shown below.*

[image]
[image]

And created client secret and copied the value to make use of it in further steps.

So after done the above , we have open the ***PowerShell with run as administrator*** mode and providing the same code with credentials;

```
# Select and Connect to require account for this operation
Connect-AzAccount
#Provide your Office 365 Tenant Domain Name or Tenant Id
$TenantId = "1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx20"
#$TenantId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  
#Provide Application (client) Id of your app
$AppClientId="5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5e"
  
 $MsalParams = @{
    ClientId = $AppClientId
    TenantId = $TenantId
    Scopes   = "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All"
}
 
$MsalResponse = Get-MsalToken @MsalParams
$AccessToken  = $MsalResponse.AccessToken
```

And then after run it will redirect to ask you the login account default or to use another account . Then select another account and provide the credentials.

[image]

***OUTPUT SCREENSHOT FOR REFERENCE:-***

[image]

***NOTE:-*** ***You can use `Connect-AzAccount` and from there select another account provide your details and when it will redirect to ask login you can select that account from the pop-up itself and provide your password and it will work. Also try to restart the PowerShell once that might help also.***

*For more information please refer this* **SO THREAD**|[***Running PowerShell as another user, and launching a script***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68980223) .

Comment: Ajay, thank you so much for your effort in trying to recreate my issue. I was able to resolve my issue when I rerun the Powershell script using an admin account which then allows me to choose another account although I don't really know why.

Comment: As far as this issue goes, there is actually no need to create a client secret and grant admin consent.  My intention is I want the user to be able to consent the app request but not to access them without their consent.

Comment: For other queries you may create a new question with providing details so that we can assist you better. Thank you:)