# Powershell Remote Invoke-Command Start-Process App

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I am trying to get an application to install on a remote server using powershell. Here is the script I am using:

```
$Username = 'administrator'
$Password = 'Password'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "IP" -ScriptBlock {Start-Process -FilePath `"C:\Windows\notepad.exe" `} -credential $Cred
```

Comment: You forgot to add a question.  I assume the script is not working - if so, what issue(s) are you having?  Any error messages, etc?

Comment: yes sorry, it is not working but I don't have error messages.. That's why I think it should work

Comment: You might try using `-Verbose` with your `Invoke-Command` call to get extra information on what's happening

Comment: @bcbabrich Still no error and the notepad.exe is not running on the remote machine

Comment: @bcbabrich Maybe I should change the session  but I don't see the notepad in task manager any session

Comment: Make sure you start powershell as Admin and then use dollar sign instead of colon in the path : "\\IP\C$\Windows\notepad.exe"

Comment: @jdweng I have, now I add -Wait and I see notepad in the task manager but session ID 0

Comment: You can copy a file to the remote computer using copy-item -tosession.  If you use a share you'll probably have to schedule a task.

Comment: Doesn't that just mean it is running as System or Admin?

Comment: @jdweng The system user can access AD shares.

Comment: With Admin and dollar sign the folders do not need to be shared.

Comment: @jdweng  how i can select the session id it will run?

Comment: I know schedule a task but I try another way

Comment: See following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989750/running-powershell-as-another-user-and-launching-a-script

Comment: @jdweng but I try to do what is PowerShell command no manual....

Comment: Any thing you can do on a command line you can do in a script.

Comment: @jdweng so I didn't see a solution for my problem.
I see AsJob Run as a background job but I need the opposite

Comment: It is not a backbground job.  Background job runs aysnchronously while a foreground runs until terminates synchronously.

Comment: @jdweng so It is possible to do it?

Comment: The link show how to run an app As Admin.  The startup is not background.

Comment: If the setup files isn't stored on the remote computer you can't access them due to issues with double hop. I.e. your script running on the remote computer needs to be authenticated with the file server, but it doesn't have your actual password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't select a session # and you can run only session 0.