# powershell script to execute another script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write small powerscript to execute an existing .ps1 file as a different user account than the one that is logged in. I need to run the existing .ps1 file on a regular basis. I need a powershell script that can be double clicked to run and it executes the existing .ps1 file as different user.

This is what I have so far:

```
$username = 'username'
$password = 'password'
$script = '\\path\to\file\script.ps1'


$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword
Start-Process powershell.exe -File $script -Credential $credential
```

Seems that the credential flags might not be in the right spot.

Would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running PowerShell as another user, and launching a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989750/running-powershell-as-another-user-and-launching-a-script)

Answer (score 0):

As an aside: Using *plain-tex*t passwords, especially if stored as such in a script, is best avoided in the interest of security.

**tl;dr**

```
Start-Process powershell.exe "-File `"$script`"" -Credential $credential
```

---

[`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) has a **`-FilePath` parameter** that specifies the **target *executable*** and an ***array*-typed `-ArgumentList` parameter** that accepts all *arguments* to pass to that executable.

These two parameters are the first two *positional* parameters, so you don't strictly need to *name* them, but you must fulfill the syntax requirements for `-ArgumentList`, which means two things:

- If you pass the pass-through arguments *individually*, you must separate them with `,` (which creates an *array*).
- While not *all* pass-through arguments require *quoting*, those with special characters do, which notably includes those that *start with `-`*, because `Start-Process` will otherwise interpret them as *its* parameters.

Thus:

```
# !! May, but isn't guaranteed to work - see below.
Start-Process powershell.exe '-File', $script -Credential $credential
```

which is short for:

```
# !! May, but isn't guaranteed to work - see below.
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList '-File', $script -Credential $credential
```

Unfortunately, a **long-standing bug that won't be fixed in the interest of backward compatibility makes this approach *brittle***, because PowerShell does *not* apply on-demand double-quoting and escaping for you when it constructs the process command line behind the scenes - see [GitHub issue #5576](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576).

You must therefore perform any embedded double-quoting and escaping *yourself*, which is **ultimately easier** to do if you **pass a *single* string to `-ArgumentList` that encodes *all* arguments to pass, using embedded double-quoting and escaping as needed**, as shown in the solution at the top.

Answer (score 0):

As mklement0 correctly noted, it is better not to use passwords explicitly.
I suggest using start-job instead of running a separate script. Plus, I will add password encryption functions on my own.

```
function setCred($role,$credPath){
    $credMassiv = @()
    if (Test-Path "$credPath\cred.csv"){$credMassiv = @(Import-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path "$credPath\cred.csv")}
    else {$credMassiv = @()}
    $array = "" | Select user, Encrypted, role
    $array.user = read-host "user for $role"
    $pwd = read-host "password:" -AsSecureString
    $array.Encrypted = ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $pwd
    $array.role = $role
    $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $array.user, $pwd
    $credMassiv += $array
    $credMassiv |Export-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8 -Path "$credPath\cred.csv"


    $cred
}



function getCred($role,$credPath){
$credMassiv = @()
$array = "" | Select user, Encrypted, role
    if (!(Test-Path "$credPath\cred.csv")){ $cred = setCred $role $credPath }

    if (Test-Path "$credPath\cred.csv"){
        $credMassiv = Import-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path "$credPath\cred.csv"

        $user = $credMassiv |Where-Object {$_.role -eq $role} |Select-Object -Expand user
        $pwd = $credMassiv |Where-Object {$_.role -eq $role} |Select-Object -Expand Encrypted | ConvertTo-SecureString
        
        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($pwd)){$cred = setCred $role $credPath}
        else {$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $pwd}
    }
    

$cred
}

$credential = get-cred "worker" $PSScriptRoot

$ScriptBlock = {
 param($path)
 write-host $path

}

          $temp = Start-Job -name "script" -Credential $credential -ArgumentList "C:\test" -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock 
Get-Job -Name "script"
```

output:
C:\test